# Substracting columns of two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables in a database, `communities` and `daily_shares` and I would like to make the difference of the sum of the first one with the second one:

```
INSERT INTO
        shares_diff (`date`, `shares_copylink`, `shares_email`, `shares_facebook`, `shares_messenger`, 
        `shares_pinterest`, `shares_twitter`, `shares_whatsapp`)
SELECT CURDATE() AS date,  
        SUM(shares_copylink) FROM communities - SUM(shares_copylink) FROM daily_shares,
        SUM(shares_email) FROM communities - SUM(shares_copylink) FROM daily_shares, 
        SUM(shares_facebook) FROM communities - SUM(shares_copylink) FROM daily_shares, 
        SUM(shares_messenger) FROM communities - SUM(shares_copylink) FROM daily_shares, 
        SUM(shares_pinterest) FROM communities - SUM(shares_copylink) FROM daily_shares, 
        SUM(shares_twitter) FROM communities - SUM(shares_copylink) FROM daily_shares, 
        SUM(shares_whatsapp) FROM communities - SUM(shares_copylink) FROM daily_shares
        WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM daily_shares);
```

But it returns:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '- SUM(shares_copylink) FROM daily_shares,
        SUM(shares_email) FROM communi' at line 5
```

Here is [the schema](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/caa7d1/1/0):

```
CREATE TABLE communities
    (`community_id` int, `shares_copylink` int, `shares_email` int, `shares_facebook` int, `shares_messenger` int, `shares_pinterest` int, `shares_twitter` int, `shares_whatsapp` int)
;
    
INSERT INTO communities
    (`community_id`, `shares_copylink`, `shares_email`, `shares_facebook`, `shares_messenger`, `shares_pinterest`, `shares_twitter`, `shares_whatsapp`)
VALUES
    (1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (2, 2, 2, 196, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (3, 8, 20, 0, 8, 0, 0, 12),
    (6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (7, 0, 0, 32, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (8, 2, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0),
    (9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (12, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1),
    (14, 1, 1, 11, 0, 0, 0, 3),
    (16, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (59, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (60, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (61, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (62, 2, 3, 28, 0, 0, 0, 9),
    (65, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (66, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (67, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (68, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (69, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (70, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (71, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (72, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (73, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (74, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (75, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (76, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (77, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (78, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (79, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (80, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (81, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (82, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (83, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (84, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (85, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (86, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (87, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (88, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (89, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (90, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (91, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (93, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (94, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (95, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (96, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (97, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (98, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (99, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (100, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (101, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (102, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (103, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (104, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 4),
    (105, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (106, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (107, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (108, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (109, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (110, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (111, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (142, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (143, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (145, 0, 1, 39, 1, 0, 0, 4),
    (146, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (147, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (148, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)
;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS shares_diff 
   (
     date DATE, 
     shares_copylink INT,
     shares_email INT,
     shares_facebook INT,
     shares_messenger INT,
     shares_pinterest INT,
     shares_twitter INT,
     shares_whatsapp INT
   );
   
INSERT INTO
shares_diff (`date`, `shares_copylink`, `shares_email`, `shares_facebook`, `shares_messenger`, 
                     `shares_pinterest`, `shares_twitter`, `shares_whatsapp`)
SELECT
  CURDATE() as date,
  SUM(shares_copylink), SUM(shares_email), SUM(shares_facebook), SUM(shares_messenger), 
  SUM(shares_pinterest), SUM(shares_twitter), SUM(shares_whatsapp)
  FROM communities
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM shares_diff);
```

I use MySQL 5.7

Comment: I don't use MySql very often so I can't speak to any specific syntax errors, but try putting parentheses around each sum, i.e.
(SUM(shares_copylink) FROM communities) - (SUM(shares_copylink) FROM daily_shares)
Also, I would suggest removing all but one difference to keep things simple, until you get it working, then add the others back in.

Comment: Also, in a similar vain of keeping things simple, get rid of the insert part for the time being. If it doesn't work as a select statement, then it won't work as an insert, and you're just making things harder on yourself.

Comment: what is the `WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM daily_shares)` part supposed to do?

Comment: I did not find the table `daily_shares` in your fiddle. Also, post your expected output.

Answer (score 0):

I can only imagine that you really want something like this:

```
SELECT CURDATE() AS date,  
       c.shares_copylink - d.shares_copylink,
       c.shares_email) - d.shares_copylink
       . . .
FROM (SELECT SUM(shares_copylink) as shares_copylink,
             SUM(shares_email) as shares_email
             . . . 
      FROM daily_shares
     ) d CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT SUM(shares_copylink) as shares_copylink,
             SUM(shares_email) as shares_email
             . . . 
      FROM communities
     ) c;
```

That is, aggregate the tables once in the `FROM` clause.